# drop down sliding underneath content.. i have tried EVERYTHing.. :(

Tags: html, css

Hey guys, ive been working on this drop down for wayyy to long now.  I just cant get the drop down to fall on top of the main content on the page.  I have tried adding position: relative and z-index on all relevant areas.

I think what may be causing the problem is "overflow: hidden" in some places.. but that is by far my favorite way to contain floats..

http://dev.redstoneinvestments.com/index.php?s=&p=redstone&v=home

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove position: relative and overflow: hidden from both header and maincontent. If you need to clear the floats, use the clearfix method: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/css-fudamentals-containing-children/ (this article specifically explains why clearfix is a better solution than overflow: hidden when you have absolutely positioned elements that need to extend outside the container).

Comment: thank you so much. i have been looking for a better way to clear float besides overflow:hidden and adding extra divs.  this works.

Answer (score 0):

change #header css to

```
#header {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    height:140px;
    width:900px;
}
```

that enough, it fixed the problem on my firefox.

Comment: that didnt change anything for me, except it covered up the breadcrumbs on pages besides front page where there are none :(

Comment: what browser/version are you using?